# How do I recover a deleted Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Yesterday a group I've created and administrated was deleted. I thought it was not possible to delete it as long as the admin remains in the group.

Now that everything disappeared, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110511115936AAXqGkC), it cannot be recovered and you'd have to create a new one.

If you'd like you can post this question on the Facebook Group Help [page](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/?id=414).